# Laravel Test Case Exception while using Mockery

Tags: laravel, testing, mockery

##### `User` model

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    const TYPE_MERCHANT = 'merchant';
    const TYPE_AFFILIATE = 'affiliate';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'type'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function merchant(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Merchant::class);
    }

    public function affiliate(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Affiliate::class);
    }
}
```

##### `Merchant` model

```php
class Merchant extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'domain',
        'display_name',
        'turn_customers_into_affiliates',
        'default_commission_rate'
    ];

    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function orders(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }
}
```

##### `Affiliate` model

```php
class Affiliate extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'merchant_id',
        'commission_rate',
        'discount_code'
    ];

    public function merchant()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Merchant::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }
}
```

##### `Order` model

```php
class Order extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    const STATUS_UNPAID = 'unpaid';
    const STATUS_PAID = 'paid';

    protected $fillable = [
        'external_order_id',
        'merchant_id',
        'affiliate_id',
        'subtotal',
        'commission_owed',
        'payout_status',
        'customer_email',
        'created_at'
    ];

    public function merchant()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Merchant::class);
    }

    public function affiliate()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Affiliate::class);
    }
}
```

##### `OrderServiceTest` Case

```php
class OrderServiceTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase, WithFaker;

    protected Merchant $merchant;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->merchant = Merchant::factory()
            ->for(User::factory())
            ->create();
    }

    protected function getOrderService(): OrderService
    {
        return $this->app->make(OrderService::class);
    }

    public function test_create_order()
    {
        $data = [
            'order_id' => $this->faker->uuid(),
            'subtotal_price' => round(rand(100, 999) / 3, 2),
            'merchant_domain' => $this->merchant->domain,
            'discount_code' => $this->faker->uuid(),
            'customer_email' => $this->faker->email(),
            'customer_name' => $this->faker->name()
        ];

        /** @var Affiliate $affiliate */
        $affiliate = Affiliate::factory()
            ->for($this->merchant)
            ->for(User::factory())
            ->create([
                'discount_code' => $data['discount_code']
            ]);

        $this->mock(AffiliateService::class)
            ->shouldReceive('register')
            ->once()
            ->with(\Mockery::on(fn ($model) => $model->is($this->merchant)), $data['customer_email'], $data['customer_name'], 0.1);

        $this->getOrderService()->processOrder($data);

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('orders', [
            'subtotal' => $data['subtotal_price'],
            'affiliate_id' => $affiliate->id,
            'merchant_id' => $this->merchant->id,
            'commission_owed' => $data['subtotal_price'] * $affiliate->commission_rate,
            'external_order_id' => $data['order_id']
        ]);
    }

    public function test_process_duplicate_order()
    {
        /** @var Order $order */
        $order = Order::factory()
            ->for(Merchant::factory()->for(User::factory()))
            ->create();

        $data = [
            'order_id' => $order->external_order_id,
            'subtotal_price' => round(rand(100, 999) / 3, 2),
            'merchant_domain' => $this->merchant->domain,
            'discount_code' => $this->faker->uuid(),
            'customer_email' => $this->faker->email(),
            'customer_name' => $this->faker->name()
        ];

        $this->getOrderService()->processOrder($data);

        $this->assertDatabaseCount('orders', 1);
    }
}
```

This is the test case that I am trying to pass, as this test case is given by the client so I can not modify the test case at all below is the given solution which I have written

##### `OrderService`  Class

```php
class OrderService
{
    public function __construct(
        protected AffiliateService $affiliateService,
        protected  ApiService $apiService
    ) {}

    /**
     * Process an order and log any commissions.
     * This should create a new affiliate if the customer_email is not already associated with one.
     * This method should also ignore duplicates based on order_id.
     *
     * @param  array{order_id: string, subtotal_price: float, merchant_domain: string, discount_code: string, customer_email: string, customer_name: string} $data
     * @return void
     */
    public function processOrder(array $data): void
    {
        if(!$this->getOrderByExternalOrderId($data['order_id'])){
            $merchant =  Merchant::where('domain', $data['merchant_domain'])->firstOrFail();
            $affiliate = Affiliate::where('user_id', function ($query) use ($data) {
                $query->select('id')
                    ->from('users')
                    ->where('email', $data['customer_email']);
            })->first();

            if (!$affiliate) {
                $affiliate = $this->affiliateService->register($merchant, $data['customer_email'], $data['customer_name'], 0.1);
            }

            $order = new Order([
                'external_order_id' => $data['order_id'],
                'subtotal' => $data['subtotal_price'],
                'affiliate_id' => $affiliate->id,
                'merchant_id' => $merchant->id,
                'commission_owed' => $data['subtotal_price'] * $affiliate->commission_rate,
            ]);

            $order->save();
        }
    }



    public function getOrderByExternalOrderId($externalOrderId){
        return Order::where('external_order_id', $externalOrderId)->first();
    }
}
```

##### `Affilate Service`

```
class AffiliateService
{
    public function __construct(
        protected ApiService $apiService,
        protected  Affiliate $affiliate
    ) {}

    /**
     * Create a new affiliate for the merchant with the given commission rate.
     *
     * @param  Merchant $merchant
     * @param  string $email
     * @param  string $name
     * @param  float $commissionRate
     * @return Affiliate
     */
    public function register(Merchant $merchant, string $email, string $name, float $commissionRate): Affiliate
    {

        if ($this->getAffiliate($email)) {
            throw new AffiliateCreateException('User already exists');
        }

        $affiliateUser  =  User::create([
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            'type' => User::TYPE_AFFILIATE,
        ]);

        $discountCode = $this->apiService->createDiscountCode($merchant);

        $affiliate = $this->affiliate->create([
            'user_id' => $affiliateUser->id,
            'merchant_id' => $merchant->id,
            'commission_rate' => $commissionRate,
            'discount_code' => $discountCode['code'],
        ]);
        Mail::to($email)->send(new AffiliateCreated($affiliate));
        return $affiliate;
    }

    public function getAffiliate($email): ?User
    {
         return  User::where('email',$email)->first();
    }
}
```

#### But I am getting the following error

```
Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException : Received Mockery_3_App_Models_Affiliate::getAttribute(), but no expectations were specified
 /Users/mac/Downloads/testProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:2222
 /Users/mac/Downloads/testProject/app/Services/OrderService.php:43
 /Users/mac/Downloads/testProject/tests/Feature/Services/OrderServiceTest.php:59
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You have an error in the test, but you do not place the code of your test. It is the first thing you should put

Comment: I am 100% sure you are mocking a model, I am tired of writing this but you do not mock models. Models and Controllers must never be mocked, for models, in this case, you have to use factories and a test database to put fake data and let the model do its thing... check my StackOverflow profile, you will find more resources about testing that should help you... still, post the test as it is the most important code and you did not share it at all

Comment: @MrEduar Sorry about that, according to me I have done that, but its like I was totally exhausted from that test case, As I have tried numerous things for at least 8 to 10 hours but nothing work that's why I posted the question but I was like sleepy and exhausted at the same time so  I made numerous mistakes while asking the question.

Comment: @matiaslauriti I have added the test case, and sorry about that.  And one more thing the test cases are the client requirement  I just have to write solution to resolve them so I cannot modify the test cases

Comment: @WasimRasheed Can you tell us which exact line is `43` on `/Users/mac/Downloads/testProject/app/Services/OrderService.php`?

Comment: @matiaslauriti its this ```affiliate_id' => $affiliate->id```

Comment: @WasimRasheed I honestly do not know what to say, something is mocking the model and you are not sharing that part, maybe the test case is doing so, I do not know, it is very weird

Comment: @matiaslauriti TBH I have shared like every piece of code and I am also amazed by this like why its happening.